# Is it ok to use multiple HttpClient instance?

Tags: c#, http, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient, http-method

I am using .NET Framework 4.5. I can't able to use IHttpClientFactory , so I decided to use single static HttpClient instance but the problem is ,if I add a Header to Client for one request it affect another request(request are from multiple threads and all request are parallel).

So my question is "what is major drawback of using multiple HttpClient instance except socket exhaustion ??"

To prevent Socket exhaustion, I close the connection immediately

```
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
```

By using multiple HttpClient instance, what are problem will i expect ? Please let me know the suggestions

P.S : I am newbie to C# as well as .NET Framework

Comment: One option is to not set headers on the client and set them on the request instead.

Comment: I am using GetAsync() / PostAsync() methods not SendAsync() . Here i am not using HttpRequestMessage to specify header in request.Only way to specify the header in HttpClient instance only :(

Comment: According to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/#considerations the best option would be to have one instance of `HttpClient` for each set of headers

Comment: Yes. They mentioned if we want different headers configuration we have to create another instance.  These are  Mentioned In Article -->                                                                                                        
" Be careful about setting properties on shared objects, as this can lead to race conditions. For example, setting DefaultRequestHeaders on the HttpClient class before each request can create a race condition. Set such properties once (for example, during startup), and **create separate instances if you need to configure different settings.**
"